# moveitcpp vs movegroup

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is out of curiosity. When is important to use moveitcpp instead of movegroup(advantages and inconvenience). If the goal was a commercial application, would moveitcpp be better and why.

I have already gotten some response but curios to hear more from other people that have used both.

@AndyZe
One advantage is decreased latency.

Some disadvantages are:

Can only be used with C++
Less tutorial documentation.
I'd be interested to hear more pros/cons, too!

Well, you have reminded me of another advantage of moveit_cpp:

You can do things like combine trajectories more easily, or run your own post-processign with moveit_cpp. That's not really an option with MGI.

@ v4hn
If you want detailed control over the C++ datastructures that do the actual planning, you need MoveItCpp instead or have to do the whole class setup that MoveItCpp does for you by yourself. That's pretty much the whole story.

Edit:
Thanks for your answers so far

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375542/moveitcpp-vs-movegroup/) by [Steven55555](https://answers.ros.org/users/72550/steven55555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-06**:
There was quite some discussion already on [ros-planning/moveit#2581](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2581).

To avoid duplicating all of that, please summarise it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveGroupInterface is generally easier if you know ROS already, and there is more documentation as it's been around longer.

moveitcpp might require more experience in C++ but gives you more control over moveit processes. I'd recommend it if you need to do 'realtime' applications (catching a ball, contact tasks) or want more control over memory (limited hardware). (Edit: Incorrect, my bad. Thanks to @v4hn and [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) :)

The company that maintains MoveIt is actively improving moveitcpp, so more documentation will emerge over time :)

---

Originally posted by [makr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45234/makr/) with karma: 179 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven55555](https://answers.ros.org/users/72550/steven55555/) on 2021-04-06**:
Thanks for your comment

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2021-04-07**:\

> I'd recommend it if you need to do 'realtime' applications (catching a ball, contact tasks)

I definitely would not! Except for the pilz planners (which are no real planners), all other planners are definitely not meant for real-time servoing / real-time feedback. [moveit_servo](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_ros/moveit_servo) is meant for such tasks, but does not provide sophisticated global planning. Hybrid planners for mixed applications are being developed, but I'm not aware of solutions you can just throw at your problems.

> or want more control over memory (limited hardware).

A more critical aspect is actually thread-control. If you use the MoveGroupInterface, the planner will actually run in a thread in the `move_group` ROS node. This is good because it means there is only one true PlanningScene - the scene in that node. But it's bad if you want to control the thread directly or run multiple planners in different threads.

**Comment by [makr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45234/makr/) on 2021-04-07**:
Thank you for the corrections!

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-04-08**:
An advantage of MGI: you can inspect all of the commands easily with the usual ROS tools. `rostopic echo` and `rosbag record`. If you go the moveit_cpp route, you'll be writing a lot of print statements and recompiling to debug.   ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-09**:\

> If you go the moveit_cpp route, you'll be writing a lot of print statements and recompiling to debug. ;)

unless you add debug publishers at strategic points :)